# Failed to build multi broker kafka with wurstmeister/kafka docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I tried several docker-compose.yml to build kafka cluster with wurstmeister docker image on my owner server but still failed so far.
Currently, my docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: "2"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka1:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9095:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://10.227.76.112:9095
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9095
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  kafka2:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9096:9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9093,OUTSIDE://10.227.76.112:9096
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9093,OUTSIDE://:9096
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  kafka3:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9097:9094"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9094,OUTSIDE://10.227.76.112:9097
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9094,OUTSIDE://:9097
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

After starting the containers using docker-compose, all container are up:
[image]

While I tried to connect to my kafka(producing a mocked message) cluster outside the server by Java API, the errors are like

```
16:14:23.027 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initialize connection to node 10.227.76.112:9094 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
16:14:23.027 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating connection to node 10.227.76.112:9094 (id: -1 rack: null) using address /10.227.76.112
16:14:23.044 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection with /10.227.76.112 disconnected
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:716)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:219)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:530)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:544)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:325)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:240)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
16:14:23.045 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
16:14:23.045 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (/10.227.76.112:9094) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
16:14:23.045 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker 10.227.76.112:9094 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

BTW, the is no firewall opened on my server.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with the wurstmeister image, but FWIW you can find a working example of multi-broker Kafka on Docker here: https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/448b807c957a1fd9e3938a5551c8f143b216903a/ccloud-replicator/docker-compose.yml#L1-L63

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I tried the yml file, but still failed. The error msg is:`===> User
uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)
===> Configuring ...
===> Running preflight checks ...
===> Check if /var/lib/kafka/data is writable ...
Command [/usr/local/bin/dub path /var/lib/kafka/data writable] FAILED !`

Comment: If you are open to using the one I've suggested then edit your question accordingly and I will post an answer - back & forth in comments gets confusing

Comment: What are you hoping to gain from running multiple brokers on one machine?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Thanks a lot for your help. I've successfully built cluster with confluent kafka docker image.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm a kafka beginner and just want to learn some cluster knowledge by testing them.